# Allegro 5 - creating a custom bitmap with alpha channel

Tags: c++, bitmap, alpha, allegro

**Afternoon everyone,**

I was wondering if there's any way I could create a custom bitmap with alpha channel

```
bitmap = al_create_bitmap(30, 30);
al_set_target_bitmap(bitmap);
al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255,255,255));
....
al_draw_tinted_bitmap(bitmap, al_map_rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),  X,  Y, 0);
```

I'm sure that I'm either not creating or drawing the bitmap correctly, so I could really use some advice.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after I set the

```
al_set_blender(ALLEGRO_ADD, ALLEGRO_ALPHA, ALLEGRO_INVERSE_ALPHA);
```

it allowed me to draw my "bouncer" bitmap and change its alpha channel using the below function:

```
al_draw_tinted_bitmap(bouncer, al_map_rgba_f(1, 1, 1, alpha) 40, 0, 0);
```

This previously did not work , so I guess adding the al_set_blender solved the "mistery".

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing wrong with your code snippet is:

```
al_map_rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
```

should be:

```
al_map_rgba_f(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
```

The former range is an integer from 0 to 255.

Also, keep in mind that Allegro's default blender is  [pre-multiplied alpha](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/08/premultiplied-alpha-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx). So if you wanted to tint red at 50%, you'd use:

```
float a = 0.5;
... al_map_rgba_f(1.0 * a, 0.0 * a, 0.0 * a, a) ...
```

If you're not thinking about it, you're probably assuming it's interpolating. i.e., the more intuitive blender for most people seems to be:

```
al_set_blender(ALLEGRO_ADD, ALLEGRO_ALPHA, ALLEGRO_INVERSE_ALPHA)
```

but that is not the default for the reasons mentioned in the above link.

Comment: tried to amend it as you advised above, but I'm till getting a blank screen as if the bitmap couldn't be displayed.